# How do I get "reputation" on this site?

Tags: discussion

Every time I try to do anything on this site I apparently lack the reputation required to do it. (Add a comment, vote up a comment that worked well for me, trying to add a tag to ask this question... basically everything I've tried to do on here thus far.)

I'd like to be able to interact in this community: how do I obtain sufficient reputation to be able to do anything? How does this system work? (At time of writing, I'm half expecting that I'm about to be told that I can't ask this question because of my lack of "reputation".)

I'm not primarily linux user and generally will be asking and responding to the baby-in-a-sandbox end of the questions spectrum.

Cheers,

Will

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work The one thing you can *always* do is ask questions. (You just need 1 rep for that and your rep can *never* go below 1.)

Comment: Thanks for the info folks. 

This explains a lot - though it is kind of annoying, it also explains the graveyard of one questions wonders on here. I think I'm going to leave the tag unchanged - I expect that a lot of starters are going to be looking for this question under this tag. I would never have found the meta or the tour without instruction. I was looking for this info but using incorrect search terms "getting started", "ask ubuntu manual" etc. etc.

Comment: I suggest you click on the "Help" link on the top of the page. From there, you can take the [tour] and also visit the [help] where everything is explained.

Comment: @Tachyons I quite agree. It is a duplication now it is here. I did not post it here. I did not know that the meta existed when I made this post. It might actually have been useful if left on askubuntu. I tried to make this point in my above comment. No new user is going to find it here - they aren't going to find the other one that is on the meta either - this will be an ongoing problem for this site.

Would you recommend that I delete my question? Will someone else just delete the question for duplication anyway?

Comment: No, don't delete it. Duplicate posts are left as sign posts for someone else. We (try to) assume you've done some research when you ask a question. Obviously if you asked a new one it was because you didn't find the first. Arguably someone else, later, will do the same thing you did. If they find your post but not the other they'll still get their answer without asking yet another question :)